# Macbook Pro won't boot after 13.10 upgrade

Tags: updates

I tried to update my macbook pro to Ubuntu 13.10, I was on 13.04. So I used the update app and then it downloaded and installed. Then I turned down the brightness and left it.

After a while I tried to turn the brightness back up but it didn't react. So I rebooted it but it displays:

```
Filesystem check or mount failed. A maintenance shell will now be started.
Control-D will terminate this shell and continue booting after retrying filesystems. 
any further errors will be ignored.
```

As I'm a Ubuntu newbie I'd appreciate it of somebody could help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this would help you**

- Start your system in **Recovery Mode**, 2nd option from Grub Menu. If your system boots automatically then you may have to hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> key while booting.
- When starts in **Recovery Mode** you would get some options, go to **fsck** option there and press **yes** when prompt to check the file system.
- Then go to **grub** option listed there and again **yes** when prompt to mount your system in read/write mode.
- Again to go **dpkg** option it will fix any broken packages, you may have to enable **network** by going to **network** option there. Chose **yes** for all.
- Finally go to **root** option and execute following commands:

  ```
  apt-get -f install
  apt-get autoremove && apt-get autoclean
  dpkg --configure -a
  update-initramfs -u
  update-grub
  reboot
  ```

Once your system reboots you would be able to login without any problem.

Reply if something goes wrong.